# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException, no errors in Connection Inspector, Thread 1 Breakpoint 1.1, multiple errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I have had multiple errors with my segue to new View Controller lately. When I run it without breakpoints and move from the initial VC to the "Submit Post" one I get the following error:

[image: ![Without Breakpoints]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kzvo.png):

Without Breakpoints

=====

So I added an Exception Breakpoint and tried running the app and here's what I got:
[image]

=====

Now, I'm relatively new to Swift development, so I googled this issue and tried nearly everything. I triple checked Connections Inspector on all of my VCs and found no warning symbols. I also tried using Product -> Clean and I rebooted my computer. Any ideas as to what could be wrong and how I can fix it?

EDIT:
In the above text I was running the app on my iPhone 5S. I tried running it in the simulator and received the same Thread 1 Breakpoint 1.1 error except on the

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

line in my AppDelegate.swift file.

I tried running it without breakpoints in the simulator and received a Thread 1: signal SIGBRT error on the same line.

I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the object key is "username", look at firebase documentation/forums. It could be "_username" for example.

Edit:
Having looked a bit more at how firebase works it looks like every field in the JSON structure is set out by you, so double check that your signup code sets the username under the key "username"

Comment: So I checked my account creation code and it seems as if everything is fine. I'm new to Swift and Firebase so I am not fully aware of everything that is happening. As such, here are the two files in question. Is there any chance you could help me solve this issue within these files? Many thanks! Account Creation: https://ideone.com/7fpYWo     Submit Post: https://ideone.com/qUyeJH

Comment: Ah yeah, so the key for the username is "author". In which case try: let currentUser = snapshot.value.objectForKey("author") as! String

Comment: So I tried that but it still gives me the same SIGABRT error in the AppDelegate file. I figured that was the case, I just wanted to make sure I was doing the right thing.

Comment: hmm, weird. if you just print out the snapshot value what does it say in the console? e.g. print(snapshot.value)

Comment: Ok, in that case it looks like snapshot is nil, although you still have objectForKey("user") rather than "author", is that intentional?

Comment: What happens when you remove that line and just type: print(snapshot.value)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108383/discussion-between-olivier-wilkinson-and-ichiro-t).